# What is the best way to write a makefile from a makefile

Tags: python, linux, makefile

I am trying to write a rules file (makefile) from a makefile, I used echo command to do it, 
but when I come to the part with $, I cannot figure out how to do it right.

I tried :

```
$(shell echo -e "#!/usr/bin/make -f \nPYTHON3=\"$(shell py3versions -vr)\"" >>text.txt
```

But I got error message saying that:

```
 py3versions: error parsing Python-Version attribute
```

The code I want to write to a rules file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/make -f 

 PYTHON3=$(shell py3versions -vr)

 %:
     dh $@   python3 --buildsystem=python_distutils

 override_dh_auto_build: $(PYTHON3:%=build-python%)

 ......
```

Anyone can give some suggestions about which command I should use to create such file? 
If use echo command, what is the way to input $?

To update my situation:

I am trying to build a python debian package. The rules file shown above is the way to build it. (of course after calling other functions like

```
python  setup.py sdist
```

and

```
py2dsc,
```

then this rules (it is called rules instead of makefile) file will be called to build the debian package.

The rules file can be automatically generated by py2dsc command, but I need to modify it to make it work for different versions of python (say, python2.* and python3.* ) . So I am thinking just write the rules file from makefile (which will call python setup.py sdist and py2dsc and this rules file) for python2.* and python3.* .

Now I am facing the problem : how Can I write the shell command the way it is to the rules file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The added info here doesn't help much.  There's no way that the makefile you show above can work, so that can't be "the way to build it".  For example, the prerequisite `$(PYTHON3:%=build-python%)` can't work.  It will expand to the value `build-python$(shell py3versions -vr)` which, as we've seen, will fail because the `-r` option requires an argument.  What are you _actually_ trying to run here?  What would a _successful_ invocation of `py3versions` look like?

Comment: To  make it easier for both of us: Forget about py3versions command (It is called through debuild command instead of make, when I use debuild, the rules file run well). Say we have a shell command DATE=$(shell date) (instead of that PYTHON3=$(shell py3versions -vr). I tried DATE=$(shell date) in the define part, I got output dates from the command in the rules file. But what I really want is to have just   DATE=$(shell date) (not output of execution) Can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: If what you're asking is how to show the static string `$(shell date)` rather than having make run the function `$(shell date)`, that's what I explained in my answer below: escape the `$`, then make will not expand it: `echo 'PYTHON3 = $$(shell date)'`

Answer (score 2):

Use two dollar signs (`$$`) to escape the dollar sign from make:

```
all:
         @echo 'VAR = $$VAR'
```

By the way, you shouldn't use `$(shell ...)` for this I don't think.  You don't give a complete example of your makefile, but if your `echo` command is part of a recipe just write it directly, don't use `$(shell ...)`.

Also just a note: `echo -e` is not portable and won't work on all POSIX systems.  I recommend you use `printf` instead, which can do the same thing and is portable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes this way I can get most of my contents. But when it comes to PYTHON3=$(shell py3versions -vr), I still get error message saying that py3versions: error parsing Python-Version attributes.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to try whenever you have a problem like this is to run it from your shell prompt.  If you can't run it there, then it obviously won't work when you run it from make.  When I do that: `$ py3versions -vr` I get the same error.  Looking at the help (`py3versions --help)` I can see that the `-r` option expects to get an argument: `[-r|--requested <version string>|<control file>]` so I'd try giving it one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. Yes py3versions require either another file name or a value of X-python-version attribute.  In my case, I want to write the line PYTHON3=$(shell py3versions -vr) to another file (rules) the way it is, instead of executing it. The line will be executed from the rules file (there I have X-python-version attribute set). Please point out if I misunderstand anything here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `$(shell ...)` command _runs_ the command you give it, it doesn't _write_ the command you give it.  That's why you're seeing this error: when you use the variable `$(PYTHON3)` make runs the command `py3versions -vr`, and it fails with that error.  Basically the generated makefile you show in your question doesn't seem right and I can't tell what you really want to do.  Maybe if you described, in words, what you want to do and why you need to generate a makefile?  Please edit the question with this information: long sequences of comments are difficult to manage.